# Does Alamofire support NSOperation queue?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, alamofire

I want to implement a batch of request using alamofire. I want to use NSOperation queue to manage it. Is it supported using Alamofire framework.

Comment: Please refer to these questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30955993/1180206
And 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/25570484/1180206